# Using sscanf to read from a file

Tags: c, string, fgets, scanf

How can I read lines from a file when the file has lines that are formatted in the following way:

```
<string> "<string>"
```

The first string cannot have spaces. The string within the quotes can have spaces.

After reading form the file into a `char` `array`, I tried something of the form of

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s", string1);
sscanf(buffer, "%*s \"%[^\"]\"", string2);
```

The problem is I get some strange characters for some of the lines. Most of the characters are fine but for long strings I get some characters that shouldn't appear.

EDIT:

Looks like the issue may be unrelated to `sscanf`. When I print `string1` and `string2` immediately after `sscanf` I get the correct output. The way my program is set up I have to `malloc` new memory and copy the results into a `char*`. It is when I print this latter result where the strange behavior appears. I use `char *cpystring1 = malloc(strlen(string1))` and then `memcpy(cpystring1, string1, strlen(string1)`. This has always worked for me, however, perhaps it is not the best method?

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Look at the last comment I left for details.

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy around strings between lots of buffers? You know you can tokenize with `strtok()` and friends, right?

Comment: Do `string1` and `string2` have enough space to store?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. Yes they do.

Comment: Note that `malloc(strlen(string1))` is not allocating space for the terminating null.  It needs to be `malloc(strlen(string1)+1)`, or (better) use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).  Note too that your `memcpy()` does not null terminate your copied string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. Thanks I figured out the problem. I initially allocated space adding the +1, but I was null terminating both after I received the input with fgets and after I memcpy'd. Adding the +1 and null terminating a single time solved the problem.

Comment: Consider using the `m` modifier to get scanf to do the malloc for you.  This will work on most newer system (POSIX-2008 and later), but may not work on older systems, or on windows.

Answer (score 1):

As [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073288/using-sscanf-to-read-from-a-file#comment42662082_27073288), one issue is "do you have enough space to store the strings?"  Indeed, are your variables `char string1[SOME_SIZE];` or are they `char *string1;`, and if the latter, how do you allocate space for them?  Symptoms such as strange extra characters are commonly caused by insufficient space for the data being read.

You can combine the two operations into a single one.  You should also limit the size that you read; and you should check that your read was successful.  Assuming that you have two arrays of size 128, you might write

```
char string1[128];
char string2[128];

if (sscanf(buffer, "%127s \"%127[^\"]\"", string1, string2) != 2)
    …format error…
```

Note that the number specified in the format string is the maximum length of the string *excluding* the null byte.  This isn't entirely consistent with the rest of the library, but was established practice long before there was a C standard, and changing the rules would have broken more than it fixed.

Note, too, that with the code above you will never know whether the trailing double quote was present.  If you need that information too, you have to work a bit harder:

```
int  offset = 0;
char string1[128];
char string2[128];

if (sscanf(buffer, "%127s \"%127[^\"]\"%n", string1, string2, &offset) != 2 || offset == 0)
    …format error…
```

Finally, if you're on a POSIX system, the `m` modifier to the `%s` and `%c` and `%[…]` operations dynamically allocates the correct amount of space for the data that is read (but you pass a pointer to a `char *` for the conversion specification to use instead of a plain `char *`):

```
int  offset = 0;
char *tag = 0;
char *value = 0;

if (sscanf(buffer, "%ms \"%m[^\"]\"%n", &tag, &value, &offset) != 2 || offset == 0)
    …format error…
```

Note that some systems (such as Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite) do not support the `m` modifier, even though it is part of POSIX 2008 specification for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).  The GNU C library (found on Linux, for example) does support it.

It is worth thinking about whether `sscanf()` is the best way to process this data.  It can be used: I've just shown how (and you had most of what you need when you wrote the question).  However, it is a tricky function to use accurately — and that is being polite.  The good thing about `sscanf()`, is that you can implement "if at first you don't succeed, try, try, try again".  With the direct I/O functions like `scanf()`, you can't try again, in general.  However, you could also use string manipulation to get you the outputs you want, though the easy ways of doing so would destroy the input string:

```
char *tag = buffer + strspn(buffer, " \t");  // Skip leading blanks and tabs
char *eot = tag + strcspn(tag, " \t");    // Tag does not contain blanks or tabs
if (*eot == '\0')
    …report format error (no value after tag); do not continue…
*eot++ = '\0';                               // Null terminate the tag
char *value = eot + strspn(eot, " \t");   // Skip separating blanks and tabs
if (*value++ != '"')
    …report format error (missing open double quote); do not continue…
char *eov = strchr(value, '"');
if (eov == 0)
    …report format error (missing close double quote); do not continue…
*eov = '\0';
```

There are also other ways to do that scanning, but `strspn()` and `strcspn()` are much neglected functions that are standard in C89 and all later versions of the standard.

#### Working test code

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using GCC 4.8.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void parsing(char *buffer)
{
    char *tag = buffer + strspn(buffer, " \t");     // Skip leading blanks and tabs
    char *eot = tag + strcspn(tag, " \t");     // Tag does not contain blanks or tabs
    if (*eot == '\0')
    {
        printf("Got tag <<%s>> but no following data\n", tag);
        return;
    }
    *eot++ = '\0';                       // Null terminate the tag
    char *value = eot + strspn(eot, " \t");     // Skip separating blanks and tabs
    if (*value++ != '"')
    {
        printf("Got tag <<%s>> but it is not followed by a double-quoted string\n", tag);
        return;
    }
    char *eov = strchr(value, '"');
    if (eov == 0)
    {
        printf("Got tag <<%s>> and value <<%s>> but it is not followed by a double-quote\n", tag, value);
        return;
    }
    *eov = '\0';

    printf("<<%s>> <<%s>>\n", tag, value);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = " \ttagname \" corresponding tag \tvalue is OK \"  ";

    {
        int offset = 0;
        char string1[128];
        char string2[128];

        if (sscanf(buffer, "%127s \"%127[^\"]\"%n", string1, string2, &offset) != 2 || offset == 0)
            printf("sscanf() 1 failed\n");
        else
            printf("<<%s>> <<%s>>\n", string1, string2);
    }

    {
        int offset = 0;
        char *tag = 0;
        char *value = 0;

        if (sscanf(buffer, "%ms \"%m[^\"]\"%n", &tag, &value, &offset) != 2 || offset == 0)
            printf("sscanf() 2 failed\n");
        else
            printf("<<%s>> <<%s>>\n", tag, value);

        free(tag);
        free(value);
    }

    parsing(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<<tagname>> << corresponding tag    value is OK >>
<<tagname>> << corresponding tag    value is OK >>
<<tagname>> << corresponding tag    value is OK >>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the first occurrence of the space character in your input buffer using `strchr`:

```
char *space1 = strchr(buffer, ' ');
*space1 = '\0'; /* terminate the first string in place */
space1++; /* move pointer to beginning of string2 */

printf("String1 = \"%s\"\n", buffer);
printf("String2 = \"%s\"\n", space1);
```

Note: the code above contains no safety checks, it is meant to illustrate the idea only. I also did not include the logic of getting rid of the `"` characters surrounding the 2nd string, but that should be easy. Hint: increase `space1` by 2, and replace the last `"` by a `\0`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: you are correct about the leading whitespace, but the OP did not require it. Regarding the double quotes: I said explicitly that I did not bother with that :-) but see my last 2 sentences. Re: format errors: there's a disclaimer that "contains no safety checks". :-) The best of it that the OP realized in the meantime that his problem is not `sscanf`-related whatsoever ;-)))

Comment: OK; fair enough.  Let's remove all these comments.